# Change text from <h1> tag to one from a different div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change the text inside a  tag to the one from a selected element from a list.

This is the list: [image]

This is the corresponding html (just a part of it)

```
<div class="categories">

    <div class="cats"><a id="categoriaBtn995" class="button" href="#categoryTitle" title="button">Línea Blanca</a></div>
    <br>

    <div class="cats"><a id="categoriaBtn996" class="button" href="#categoryTitle" title="button">Desarrollo de Software</a></div>
    <br>

    <div class="cats down"><a id="categoriaBtn998" class="button" href="#categoryTitle" title="button">Esteticas - Belleza</a></div>
    <br>

    <div class="cats"><a id="categoriaBtn999" class="button" href="#categoryTitle" title="button">Publicidad</a></div>
    <br>
</div>
```

Under this div, I have a section where I want to put some info about this elements.

First, I need to change the title which is just a simple  tag:

```
<h1 id="categoryTitulo">Change this</h1>
```

It should change the text to the  element with class="down"

This is how I toggle the class:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.button').click(function () {
        $('.down').toggleClass("down");
        $(this.parentElement).toggleClass("down");

    });
});
```

And this is what I'm trying right now:

```
$('a.button').click(function () {
    $('h1#categoryTitulo').text(
        $('.down').text());
});
```

I tried to place all this in JSFIDDLE and for some reason it actually works there, but not on my site. I hope you guys can help me figure out another method to accomplish this.

This is what I'm trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/2mAfT/
But it is not working with me.

Comment: First thing first...elements cannot share IDs! They can share classes but every element must have either its own id or no id. What is not working for you? Are there any errors? Changing your `id="categoriaBtn"` to `class="categoriaBtn"` might help with your problem

Comment: Done @j_buckley, anything shares IDs now, but it is still not working, there are no errors. The text from the `h1` is not changing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your a#categoriaBtn to run off of class not id.  Something like;

```
$('a[class$="button"]').click(function(){
      $("#categoryTitulo').html('whatever you want here');
});
```

i don't know where you're getting the className of down or anything else, but that should work on whatever you want

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the script.

Comment: when you open the site in your browser click on F12 to bring up the developer tools and if IE go to the script tab select your jquery version from the drop-down next to 'Start Debugging' and make sure that it is loading properly, seems to me it would be a jQuery reference issue if it works correctly in jsFiddle with the same code.

Comment: Thank you Nick, it's working now, just needed to add  `$(document).ready(function ()` and change the order of the scripts.